# can i build a c++ class on android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I saw a lot of tutorials of native code in android app,
and always proggramers puts "extern c" surround a function before calling it from java code.

My question is if i can build a c++ class and use it directly from java code.

for example, it is my simple cpp code :

```
#ifndef NATIVEEX_MYNUMBER_H
#define NATIVEEX_MYNUMBER_H

class MyNumber
{
public:
    MyNumber();

    int getNum();

private:
    int num;
};

#endif //NATIVEEX_MYNUMBER_H
```

Is it possible to do "new MyNumber()" from java?

Comment: So I can call only  C functions(functions that surrounding with "extern c")?

Comment: yes you can use C but Not C++

Comment: Ok, thanks you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ in JNI.

You *can't*, however, combine C++ objects with Java objects.  The JVM is not set up for that.  So in JNI, instead of a C++ object, you get a reference to a Java object, and your C++ code operates on that.  Remember, JNI code is still running in a Java/JVM environment, so your native C++ code has to respect that.

Now, that doesn't mean you can't still use C++ classes in JNI.  You just can't pass them back and forth freely to the JVM.

The `extern "C"` directive is used to prevent something that happens during C++ compilation and linking called *name mangling*.  C++ uses name mangling to support method overloading using different parameter types.

Name mangling needs to be disabled in order to preserve the function name in the external library so the JVM can link to it.  Functions that aren't being called through JNI don't need the `extern "C"` wrapper.

Along those same lines, C++ exceptions can't be thrown directly back through JNI.  All C++ exceptions need to be caught and handled, which may mean creating a Java exception and calling the `JNIEnv` `throwNew` method.

Further info here: [Name Mangling and extern “C” in C++ - GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/)